# How to allow access to only particular GKE clusters and not all using IAM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am not getting, how to allow access to only a particular GKE cluster or a particular compute engine only, rather than giving permission to all GKE clusters or VM's.

Comment: Hello! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi did you eventually find a solution for this? Am also looking for a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to provide access to a particular object within a Kubernetes cluster, use **Kubernetes Role-based Access Control**.

> Kubernetes has built-in support for RBAC that allows you to create
> fine-grained Roles, which exist within the Kubernetes cluster.
>
> A Role can be scoped to a specific Kubernetes object or a type of
> Kubernetes object, and defines which actions (called verbs) the Role
> grants in relation to that object. A RoleBinding is also a Kubernetes
> object, and grants Roles to users.
>
> In a GKE user can be any of:
>
> - Google Cloud user
> - Google Cloud service account
> - Kubernetes service account
> - Google Workspace user
> - Google Workspace Google Group

More information about [Authorize actions in clusters using role-based access control](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control)

Comment: So that means (right?) that if i have 5 clusters, i want to grant access to one, i need to assign `roles/container.viewer` and then go to the other 4 clusters and dis-allow access for the user..?